# Is it possible to get datasource for external jar from Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

I can't inject datasource in a separate jar file for the quarkus server.

I added an empty file to META-INF/beans.xml in my separated project that creates jar for my quarkus server. Then I declared my class with annotation @ApplicationScoped and added a Datasource field (also tried with AgroalDataSource) with annotation @Inject.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeClassInExternalJar {

    @Inject
    DataSource dataSource;

    //dummy code
    public void someMethod() {
       Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
       //...
    }
```

But I get null value of dataSource.
I confirm that the datasource is configured correctly, because in the server itself the operations with the database occurs successfully.

Comment: Hello there,
Did you add the empty beans.xml into the separate jar file or into the main one that would use the separate jar?

Comment: @NándorHolozsnyák Hi! I added empty beans.xml into the separate jar file.